# print statement -Java syntax array elements

Tags: java, printf

```
do {    
    System.out.print("arrPascal["+i+"]["+j+"]   = ");
    System.out.println(arrPascal[i][j]);)
    fibo += arrPascal[i][j];
    i--;
    j++;
}
```

I am trying to print

```
arrPascal[58][9]  = 10648873950\n
arrPascal[57][10] = 43183019880\n
```

But my code results in

```
arrPascal[58][9]   = 10648873950\n
arrPascal[57][10]   = 43183019880\n
```

How to make sure this code lines up "= " for all results from `("arrPascal["+i+"]["+j+"]   = ");`

Comment: Use `System.out.format(...)` instead of `System.out.print(...)`. It gives you much better control over the widths of elements.

Comment: Check https://www.baeldung.com/java-pad-string#3-using-stringformat

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.out.format` with the width specifier. You can either hardcode a width that is larger than any possible width you will need or you can calculate it based on the maximum length of any of the `String`s you need to print.

```
System.out.format("%-19s = %d%n", "arrPascal[" + i +"][" + j + "]", arrPascal[i][j]);
//width is 19, left aligned
```